# MATLAB: finding the bottom diagonal layer in binary

Tags: matlab, image-processing, binary, selection, layer

I have a binary image with several layers-often diagonal and of different widths and am trying to find the bottom layer. In other words I cannot rely on the minimum Y value of the layer, centroid, etc.

I think the solution should have something to do with looking at a particular Y value which multiple layers cross over, and selecting the bottom layer at that value.. not sure how to code this-(specifically not sure how to find that y value)...also maybe theres a smarter way to do this?

So in the attached picture: This would start as a binary with the blue and green lines both in white. I run bwconncomps() on the binary. The green line is the one I wish to identify. The red line is where I imagine I could check for the bottom layer-but how do I find this location?

[image]

Comment: How do you define "bottom layer"? What if the one to the left of the green one in your image curls back at the bottom, below the green one? Is that the bottom then? If you can unambiguously define the *bottom* one, it should be easier (=possible) to answer.

Comment: Right..I think my trouble defining it is paralleling my difficulty finding a solution. I would say bottom=where the Y location is below the Y location of other components at the majority of X locations.

Comment: So... locate each simply connected blob, then check their mutual y-location-belowness-ratio-for-x-locations, for each pair?

Comment: That sounds right-I don't know if going by pairs is most efficient or if there's some way to rate them all within one for loop

Comment: I'll let some image-processing-savvy guys take over from here. Although if I were you, I'd first implement it *somehow*, and then worry about efficiency. Anyway, I guess you could start with a random blob, and test another one, see which is *bottomer*, then pick a new one and see if that's *even bottomer*, etc. But your *bottomness* definition should be transitive for this to work uniquely.

Comment: I don't quite understand how you define the green line as being the "bottom" layer.  What is your criteria?

Comment: @rayryeng way ahead of you, see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37647836/matlab-finding-the-bottom-diagonal-layer-in-binary?noredirect=1#comment62776086_37647836) ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this would be to find the last `1` in each column of your image. Then, after you run `bwconncomp`, you can check to see how many times a given component contained the last `1` in each column.

We can break this down into the following steps.

1. **Identify the row the contains the last `1` in each column.** There are many different ways to do this, but one way is to take the cumulative sum (`cumsum`) along the first dimension and find the row of the maximum value in each column (using `max`). This will tell us the row that contains the last `1` in each row.

   As an example:

   ```
   data = [1 0 0;
           0 0 1;
           1 1 0];

   C = cumsum(data, 1);
   %   1   0   0
   %   1   0   1
   %   2   1   1

   [~, rows] = max(C, [], 1);
   %   3   3   2
   ```
2. **Identify all connected components**. This one is easy because we can just use `bwconncomp` to get the connected components.
3. **Determine how many members of each connected component are the last `1` in their respective columns.** We can convert the `rows` that we found in step 1 to their linear index using `sub2ind`. We can then loop through all connected components and use `ismember` and `sum` to determine how many of those values occurred in a given connected components (determined using `PixelIdxList`).
4. **Use the component with the most pixels that were the last `1` in their row as the "most distance" component**. We can again use `max` on the output of step 3 to determine this.

## Putting it all together

So if we write that all out for your data it would look something like the following (ignore the first two lines because those are just needed to create the binary image from the image that you provided in your post).

```
% Load the image and convert to binary image
img = imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/flpoC.jpg');
img = img(:,:,2) > 50 | img(:,:,3) > 50;

% Determine the row which contains the last 1 in each column
C = cumsum(img, 1);
[~, rows] = max(C, [], 1);

% Now convert these rows indices to linear indices 
% (the ones that will appear in PixelIdxList)
inds = sub2ind(size(img), rows, 1:size(C, 1));

% Get connected components of the image
CC = bwconncomp(img);

% Determine the number of pixels in each component that were at the bottom
numAtBottom = cellfun(@(x)sum(ismember(inds, x)), CC.PixelIdxList);

% The one that has the most was the largest bottom-most component
[~, bottomComponent] = max(numAtBottom);
```

And to display that component as a proof of concept

```
% Just to show this, we will create a binary image of JUST that component
I = img;
I(CC.PixelIdxList{bottomComponent}) = 2;

figure, imagesc(I)
```

[image]